# How to collect logs for every event which occurs in android device?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I wanted to collect log for every event which occurs in android device like when user starts any application or when any application have notification for user.

Currently I have broadcast receiver listening for every event  but it did not listened to certain events, so I searched on internet and it suggested to give priority to events while registering then in manifest file. Now the question is should I give priority to every event and if yes what priority should I give them.

Thanks.

Comment: Quite simply, 3rd party apps are no longer permitted to do this.  You can only achieve your goal with the assistance of the organization which prepares the Android installation for the device - ie, the manufacturer or carrier, or on a "custom ROM" its authors if they have left hooks behind which form holes in the normal Android security restrictions.

Comment: You mean to say their is no way i can do this programmatically without going to android source code. Actually i have Samsung S4 (gt19505) if you can help me ? Thanks.

Comment: You can make your app an `Accessibility Service`. They can react to nearly all events. Unfortunately, TouchWiz phones start to talk to the user (TTS) as soon as you enable an `Accessibility Service` :D Not sure if they fixed it yet.

Comment: @ByteHamster you are suggesting that retrieving window content will help me to get app which user just started.

Comment: I don't really know how an `Accessibility Service` works. But I am quite sure they get an intent as soon as an app is opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessibility Service in android can react to nearly all events.