# Logging of events that occur in Android applications

Tags: android, testing, ui-testing

Are there any Android logs showing which events have occurred in the current running application and with no access to the source code for the application? Events from the user such as text input, buttons pressed, etc.

Comment: No, you'd need to write that yourself.

Comment: Have a look at this,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732402/how-to-collect-logs-for-every-event-which-occurs-in-android-device Hope,this will help you.

Comment: @PriyaJagtap That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Accessibility Service` in android can react to nearly all events.

Have a look at this,
[How to collect logs for every event which occurs in android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732402/how-to-collect-logs-for-every-event-which-occurs-in-android-device)

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Glad, It helped you @Nadeemm. I hope, this link as a answer to your questions can be helpful to many other users.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest use the **Analytics** for events from the user such as text input, buttons pressed, etc also track active users,active screen, location etc.

Use this documentation of implementing anlytics [Add Analytics to Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) I hope it will help you.